# Getting specific value from dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

is it possible to get a specific element from the dictionary? For example, I have a dictionary like this and I would like to get the third element as an integer, how can I do that?

```
public Dictionary<int, char> CodesOfLetters = new Dictionary<int, char>()
        {
              {260,'Ą'},
              {261,'ą'},
              {280,'Ę'},
              {281,'ę'},
              {362,'Ū'},
              {363,'ū'},
              {268,'Č'},
              {352,'Š'},
              {381,'Ž'},
              {269,'č'},
              {353,'š'},
              {382,'ž'},
              {278,'Ė'},
              {279,'ė'},
              {302,'Į'},
              {303,'į'},
              {370,'Ų'},
              {371,'ų'}
        };
```

Comment: " third element as an integer" Huum?the 280 or the `'Ę'`?

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered. If you care about the order in which you've inserted items, you should consider a different collection, e.g. a `List<T>`. When you say you want "the third element as an integer" what exactly do you mean? An element is a key/value pair.

Comment: I would like to get 280(int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, a `Dictionary<int,char>` is also an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int,char>>` so you can use:

```
var anElement = CodesOfLetters.ElementAt(2);
```

(as long as you have `using System.Linq` at the top of your file.)

But be aware, the order of a dictionary is not guaranteed - if you care about the order of things, you probably dont want a dictionary to start with.

---

Edit. You comment that what you want is `280` - you can also treat the `Keys` as an `IEnumerable<int>` so you could do:

```
var thirdKey = CodesOfLetters.Keys.ElementAt(2);
```

with the same caveat as above. There's no guarantee the order of the keys.

---

If you want to keep track of the order you add items to your list, but also be able to find values by key, you could create a class that wraps both a `List<int>` for the ordered list of keys, and a `Dictionary<int,char>` to be able to quickly look up values by key.

Comment: `OrderedDictionary` might be a good option instead of a regular dictionary, if they still need to get values by `Key` in addition to the index.

Comment: @Matthew possibly but yuck, no generic implementation

Comment: Thanks, I got the number with `ElementAt(2).Key`, and is it possible to get a char?

Comment: @D0mm: Have you taken on board that `ElementAt` could return you *any* element? (And if you want the value instead of the key, use the `Value` property rather than the `Key` property.)

Comment: @D0mm `ElementAt(2).Value` - but you've read the caveats, right? This isnt going to always work as you expect

Comment: SortedDictionary may be a better option than OrderedDictionary.